# Why does SomeStruct() is AnyObject return true?

Tags: swift, anyobject

I'm a bit confused by the usage of AnyObject. Let me provide a few examples.

**AnyObject**

```
NSObject() is AnyObject
```

^ true (as expected)

```
class MyClass {}
MyClass() is AnyObject
```

^ true (as expected)

```
class MyClass {}
MyClass.self is AnyObject
```

^ true (as expected)

```
String() is AnyObject
```

^ true (as NOT expected)

```
struct MyStruct {}
MyStruct() is AnyObject
```

^ true (as NOT expected; String appears to be a struct)

```
String.self is AnyObject
```

^ false (as expected)

A snippet from Apple's documentation regarding AnyObject:

> AnyObject can be used as the concrete type for an instance of any class, class type, or class-only protocol.

Why is an instance of struct is regarded as an AnyObject?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ugh, this is one of my gripes with Swift. It's an Objective C interop feature, which although useful, is too implicit/mysterious. This implicit boxing behaviour only happens when Foundation is imported, and only on systems with ObjC support (Apple's platforms).

Some Swift types bridge to specific ObjC counterparts, like `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, etc. All other swift value types (like structs and tuples) are capable of being wrapped in a private ObjC class called `_NSSwiftValue`, which makes it possible to hand them off to ObjC APIs.

The most confusing thing is that the object has an ill-defined identity (object address) as far as Objective C is concerned, and if your type doesn't conform to `Hashable`, then the Hash value of the object is also ill-defined, which can lead to all kinds of hard-to-nail-down bugs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I can understand how that might apply to String/Int/etc as there are equivalent types in Objective-C.
But - why would it happen with any arbitrary struct (like MyStruct). Is it bridging my struct into a NSDictionary?

Comment: @AlexLarson No, it's wrapping it in a box called `_NSSwiftValue`, an `NSObject` subclass whose only instance variable is the swift value typed being boxed up.

Comment: Ohhhh! I misread. Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

So basically `String` has an bridging connection to `NSString`, which is an `NSObject`. If we take the apple documentation at [This place](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfstringref) We can see that it's a `typedef struct` or `typealias` if you so will. And if we move on to look [over here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html) and scroll down in the list, we will see that in the previous link the `CFStringRef` as a `struct` is bridged to `NSString` as a `class`

Further down in Xcode we can see the documentation for `String`

> Any `String` instance can be bridged to `NSString` using the type-cast
>   operator (`as`), and any `String` instance that originates in Objective-C
>   may use an `NSString`

Which basically tells us that you can throw an `String class` to an `String struct` without any problem because they are basically the same